# ¿Cómo mantener los caracteres UTF8?

Tags: php, laravel, json, utf-8, charset

Estoy teniendo un problema, cuando recibo la respuesta del json... no me salen los caracteres especiales...
Añado a la cabecera

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([

    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

Resultado que debería de salir:

```
{

    "NOMBRE1": "PEPE MAÑEZ MARIÇA",

    "NOMBRE2": "PEPE",

    "NOMBRE3": "MAÑEZ",

}
```

Resultado final:

> "NOMBRE1":"PEPE YA\u00d1EZ MARI\u00c7A","NOMBRE2":"PEPE","NOMBRE3":"MA\u00d1EZ"

Comment: Lo que muestras como "resultado final" es el valor de ` $response->getBody()->getContents();`?

Comment: si, ese sería el resultado final.

Answer (score 1):

hazlo así:

```
json_encode($tusdatos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

para mas referencias: https://www.php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo he probado y sigue sin ir...

Comment: Esto es un tema de como está configurado el Collation de tu base de datos, intenta agregando la siguiente linea a tu archivo de conexión ``mysqli_set_charset($conn,"latin1");``